# Inject parameter at WCF service constructor using NInject

Tags: c#, wcf, ninject

I've seen several [examples on Internet](http://www.aaronstannard.com/dependency-injection-ninject-wcf-service/) setting up an NInject Factory modifying svc file. I don't have this svc file (or I don't know where's it).

I've a slight WCF service:

`IService` interface:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IFileSystemPluginService
{
    [OperationContract]
    void saveConfiguration(Configuration.Configuration configuration, string userId);

    [OperationContract]
    Configuration.Configuration getConfiguration(string userId);
}
```

`IService` implementation:

```
public class Service : IService
{
    private IUserConfigurable userConfigurablePlugin;

    public Service(IUserConfigurable configurablePlugin)
    {
        this.configurablePlugin = configurablePlugin;
    }
}
```

In order to kick the service off I'm setting configuration up in code:

```
private void initializeWCFService()
{
    string baseAdress = "xxx";
    Uri baseAddressUri = new Uri(baseAdress);

    this.serviceHost = new System.ServiceModel.ServiceHost(typeof(Service), baseAddressUri);
    this.serviceHost.AddServiceEndpoint(
        typeof(IService),
        new System.ServiceModel.WSHttpBinding(),
        string.Empty
    );

    System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceMetadataBehavior();
    smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
    smb.HttpGetUrl = new Uri(baseAdress);
    this.serviceHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
    this.serviceHost.Open();
}
```

I need to inject a `IUserConfigurable` object in `Service` constructor.

Comment: Service instance is created by ServiceHost to which we dont have access...This configurable plugin will be same throughout? will it different based on some condition?

Comment: What I mean is can configurablePlugin be static? only one instance of configurablePulgIn  for different instances of service? it will be more easy to set staic property of Service then injecting in the constructor of service